# Element creation in jQuery; create, wrap, append

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Relatively quick one;

I'm creating a few elements dynamically, and am appending them to another element.

```
$element = $('<input />', {
    // attributes
}).add('<label />', {
    // attributes
});
```

This produces `<input /><label></label>` with their respective attributes and content. I just want to wrap this in a `<div>` and thought there would be an equally clean way of doing so, but I can't seem to get the following to work:

```
$element = $('<input />', {
    // attributes
}).add('<label />', {
    // attributes
}).wrapAll('<div />');
```

If I `console.log()` my `$element`, it's only the `<input>` and `<label>`. I've also tried

```
$element = $($('<input />', {
    // attributes
}).add('<label />', {
    // attributes
})).wrapAll('<div />');
```

Selecting the to-be-appended `<input>` and `<label>` elements separately, and applying the `.wrapAll()`, but that doesn't work either, resulting in the same as above.

Am I close? Should I just go another route?

---

Ended up going with the following thanks to @mu

```
$element = $('<div />').append($('<input />', {
    // attr
}).add('<label />', {
    // attr
}));
```

Oh jQuery; seven million ways to do the same thing, and sometimes you can't figure out one.

---

**Edit**

Just adding for future visitors; the `append` method can also take an array:

```
$('<div />').append([
    $('<div />'),
    $('<div />'),
    $('<div />'),
]);
```

Which would yield:

```
<div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

So you don't need to chain calls to `append()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not just do this?

```
var $div = $('<div>').append($element);
```

For example: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/CQDe8/1/

Comment: Thanks @mu - Spot on indeed. I reworked it a bit using your technique, and its perfect, in fact more readable and brief. I'll accept in 3.

Answer (score 2):

```
element = $('<div></div').html($('<input />', {
    // attributes
}).add('<label />', {
    // attributes
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, I think you might want to use `.appendTo()` instead of `.wrapAll()`